# Why doesn't AnimatedVectorDrawable support seek?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-vectordrawable, animatedvectordrawable

At the Google IO presentation "Get Animated", Nick Butcher mentions that you can't `seekTo` on animated vector drawables.

https://youtu.be/N_x7SV3I3P0

For my purposes this is fine. I can chop up my animation in multiple smaller animations. But I still find this a glaring omission of a useful feature, which to my naive mind doesn't seem so hard to implement as part of the animation framework.

Is there a reason why this was not implemented, maybe due to some performance optimization I do not understand?